# What is the differebce between Yii::app()->user->setState() and Yii::$app->request->cookies

Tags: yii, yii2

```
Yii::app()->user->setState('ccGiftItemDetail', $giftItemDetail );
Yii::app()->user->setState ('ccSelectedMerchantId', $model->attributes ['merchantId']);
```

I have this code calling `Yii::app()->user->setState()`. I want to know where it will be saved and what the main difference between `setState()` and cookies in Yii2?

Comment: Refer : http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/48360-setstate-and-cookie/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, `Yii::app()->user->setState()` is from Yii1, and `Yii::$app->request->cookies` is from Yii2.

Pretty good explanation of what `setState()` is available in [this thread](http://yiiframework.ru/forum/viewtopic.php?t=4516) of official russian forum. The essence is it's used for saving frequently used user related data and accessing it later on. It uses both sessions and cookies, and the main advantage is it remains between different sessions.

As for `Yii::$app->request->cookies`, pretty detailed explanation with usage examples is available in official docs [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-sessions-cookies.html).

Answer (score 0):

`setState()` is used to save the value in a `session`, the function `setState()` in [CWebUser.php](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CWebUser#setState-detail) might give you a clear idea:

```
    /**
     * Stores a variable in user session.
     *
     * This function is designed to be used by CWebUser descendant classes
     * who want to store additional user information in user session.
     * By storing a variable using this function, the variable may be retrieved
     * back later using {@link getState}. The variable will be persistent
     * across page requests during a user session.
     *
     * @param string $key variable name
     * @param mixed $value variable value
     * @param mixed $defaultValue default value. If $value===$defaultValue, the variable will be
     * removed from the session
     * @see getState
     */
    public function setState($key,$value,$defaultValue=null)
    {
        $key=$this->getStateKeyPrefix().$key;
        if($value===$defaultValue)
            unset($_SESSION[$key]);
        else
            $_SESSION[$key]=$value;
    }
```

And as the name suggests `Yii::app()->request->cookies` deals with [cookies](http://us.php.net/setcookie), take a look at the function `addCookie()`, it might give you an idea:

```
    /**
     * Sends a cookie.
     * @param CHttpCookie $cookie cookie to be sent
     */
    protected function addCookie($cookie)
    {
        $value=$cookie->value;
        if($this->_request->enableCookieValidation)
            $value=Yii::app()->getSecurityManager()->hashData(serialize($value));
        if(version_compare(PHP_VERSION,'5.2.0','>='))
            setcookie($cookie->name,$value,$cookie->expire,$cookie->path,$cookie->domain,$cookie->secure,$cookie->httpOnly);
        else
            setcookie($cookie->name,$value,$cookie->expire,$cookie->path,$cookie->domain,$cookie->secure);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`Yii::$app->session->set('someextradata','somevalue')` is unique for each user.
[look here](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/167)